# why Catch block is executing after return statement in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use try catch in C# application but I am facing problem suppose first-time internet issue came and then again it tries to sync second-time internet came then after return statement it's going again in catch(CommunicationException comEx) block and return false.

why its happening

```
int SyncFailCount = 0; 
private bool SyncCustomers(long TenantId, DataTable dtCusomers)
{
   bool IsSyncSuccess = false;
    try
    {
        SyncQBClient client = new SyncQBClient();
        client.SynvCustomer(TenantId, dtCusomers);
        SyncFailCount = 0;
        IsSyncSuccess = true;
    }
    catch (CommunicationException comEx) // Mohan: Exception due to Internet issue
    {
        SyncFailCount = SyncFailCount + 1;
        Thread.Sleep(300);
        if (SyncFailCount <= 5)
        {
            SyncCustomers(TenantId, dtCusomers);                 
        }             
    }
    catch (TimeoutException TimeoutEx) // Mohan: Exception due to timeout from web service
    {
        SyncFailCount = SyncFailCount + 1;
        Thread.Sleep(300);
        if (SyncFailCount <= 5)
        {
            SyncCustomers(TenantId, dtCusomers);
        }
        SyncFailCount = 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "CashPundit", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        SyncFailCount = 0;
    }
    return IsSyncSuccess;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the catch block is executed after the return. You probably are executing multiple threads at once. Check your threads window for more details.

Comment: are you describing the story as you see it in the debugger? What exactly is your problem? I did not grasp it yet

Comment: I am using 4.0 .net framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is an exception in `SyncCustomers()` you will call `SyncCustomers`.
*As far as good.*
Let's pretend that your second run is good and would return `True` (at `return IsSyncSuccess;`)

And here is the problem, you are not catching the return statement in your exception handling - the `True` is getting lost in the catch block.

Instead of recursively calling the method, may try a while loop to get the synchronization work, no matter if there is an exception or not.

```
int SyncFailCount = 0; 
private bool SyncCustomers(long TenantId, DataTable dtCusomers)
{
    bool IsSyncSuccess = false;

    // While there is no success do the loop
    while (!IsSyncSuccess)
    {
        try
        {
            SyncQBClient client = new SyncQBClient();
            client.SynvCustomer(TenantId, dtCusomers);
            SyncFailCount = 0;
            IsSyncSuccess = true;
        }
        catch (CommunicationException comEx) // Mohan: Exception due to Internet issue
        {
            SyncFailCount = SyncFailCount + 1;
            Thread.Sleep(300);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException TimeoutEx) // Mohan: Exception due to timeout from web service
        {
            SyncFailCount = SyncFailCount + 1;
            Thread.Sleep(300);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "CashPundit", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            SyncFailCount = 0;
            break;
        }

        // If there are more than 5 Sync Fails, break the loop and return false
        if (SyncFailCount > 5)
        {
            SyncFailCount = 0;
            break;
        }   
    }

    return IsSyncSuccess;
}
```

Comment: I tried this also after break and after return statement if two times failed in
catch (CommunicationException comEx)

its making IsSyncSuccess false even third time it was sync success

Comment: So it works or it doesn't work? @Rakesh I don't know what your meaning `:/`

Answer (score 2):

Trace what is happening when there is *one* CommunicationException or TimeoutException and the Thread.Sleep "fixes" this:

- you are calling `SyncCustomers` from "outside" and setting the *local* variable `IsSyncSuccess` to `false`
- you end up in a catch block and call `SyncCustomers` again.
- this sets a *new* *local* variable `IsSyncSuccess` to `false`
- the method succeeds and returns the `true` value
- now you are back in the original version of your method, inside that catch block
- you ignore the returned value, and the value of `IsSyncSuccess` local to this original invovation of your method is still `false`. This is the value that you are returning.

So a partial solution would be to not ignore the return value when you recursively call `SyncCustomers` from within a catch block:

```
IsSyncSuccess = SyncCustomers(...);
```

But then you still have a possible infinite recursion that you need to deal with:
When there is a CommunicationException or TimeoutException, you are increasing SyncFailCount, and calling SyncCustomers again - which resets that SyncFailCount back to 0! You are never reaching that limit of 5

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure which .net framework you are using but 4.0 and above  i would recommned using Task method instead of thread This is sample only hope you can use this example

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task<int> task = new Task<int>(Test);
        task.ContinueWith(ExceptionHandler, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        task.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int Test()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    static void ExceptionHandler(Task<int> task)
    {
        var exception = task.Exception;
        Console.WriteLine(exception);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add this line at the end of each catch Block

```
return IsSyncSuccess;
```

Comment: did you try this?

Comment: the working way should be something like `return SyncCustomers(TenantId, dtCusomers);`, but it's not a good way...